# User Interaction Enabled changing text color and click-ability of other sections

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have 3 sections in a table view and only using the middle section, section 2, to show various cells. Sections 1 and 3 only show one cell and I am making them unclickable since I want to display buttons and text on them. I made them and it was working fine until I made sections 1 and 3 userInteractionEnabled=NO.

Code: **I know I can make this Object Oriented, and it was, but once this problem came up I tried to make it differently but it is still the same.**

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UIView *selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.1];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView;
        if(cell==nil) { NSLog(@"Cell is nil");}
    }

    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        cell.textLabel.text = nil;
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
        dosageButton                            = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        amountButton                            = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
        [dosageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDosages:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [amountButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showAmount) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:dosageButton];
        [self.view addSubview:amountButton];
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        return cell;
    }

    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        if (self.nameMutable.count != 0 )
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.nameMutable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",[self.priceMutable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chevron"]];
            return cell;
        }
        else
        {
            //Empty for now. Waiting for data fetching to finish
            return cell;
        }
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
        cell.accessoryView = nil;
        cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;
        return cell;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Something went wrong");
        return cell;
    }

}
```

For some reason my table view cell in section 1 where it is supposed to be clickable the color changes to a dark grey and is not clickable anymore. Its usually cell 3 and cell 10. Also, when I scroll down and Section 0 is no longer visible and then I scroll back up and Section 0 is visible, some of the cells become non-clickable and the color of the text changes.

Also, how can I make a certain cell, inside section 1, have bigger height because the text is too long to display and it starts to display "..." or covers the detailTextLabel. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

You have to remember that these cells are being reused or 'recycled' so if you're setting `userInteractionEnabled=NO` for an `if` statement you need to set it to `userInteractionEnabled=YES` in your `else` statement, or set it as `YES` before all your statements. You also want to make sure that you're adding any other subviews (buttons etc.) that are unique to certain index paths to cells that are newly created, where you would stick that piece of code inside your `if(cell==nil)` statement. Something like this:

```
-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    if(cell == nil)
    {
        cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleValue1 reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
        UIView *selectedBackgroundView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
        selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.0 alpha:0.1];
        cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedBackgroundView;
        if(indexPath.section == 0) {
            dosageButton                            = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            amountButton                            = [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect];
            [dosageButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showDosages:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [amountButton addTarget:self action:@selector(showAmount) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
            [self.view addSubview:dosageButton];
            [self.view addSubview:amountButton];
        }

        if(cell==nil) { NSLog(@"Cell is nil");}
    }

    cell.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    cell.accessoryView = nil;
    cell.textLabel.text = nil;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = nil;

    if(indexPath.section == 0)
    {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }

    else if (indexPath.section == 1)
    {
        if (self.nameMutable.count != 0 )
        {
            cell.textLabel.text = [self.nameMutable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
            cell.detailTextLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"$%@",[self.priceMutable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];
            cell.accessoryView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"chevron"]];
        }
        else
        {
            //Empty for now. Waiting for data fetching to finish
        }
    }
    else if (indexPath.section == 2)
    {
        cell.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Something went wrong");
    }
    return cell;
}
```

And if you want to change the height of certain index paths `(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` [Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UITableViewDelegate/tableView%3aheightForRowAtIndexPath%3a) delegate method.

Comment: Why would you put section 0 inside the if statement when youre making cells? (`if (cell==nil) { section 0 in here}`?)

Comment: Because if you are adding subviews to a specific cell then it's better to do it inside the if-statement so that it's only added if a new cell is created. Otherwise when scrolling you'll have other cells in the table re-using the cell and buttons will start appearing in rows you don't want them to be.

Comment: I tried doing that but the cell and button did not load, thats why I was asking. Any clue why it isn't appearing?

Comment: Have you checked that you're returning the right number of rows for section 0 in your `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection` method?

Comment: Yeah I did. The problem is that it disappears when I reload the button. I click on the button and bring up a menu option and then it has to reload because the string of the button changes size depending on the option. So I have to remove it from superview then add it back again. Any suggestions?